# Let user pick document type to create when using SwiftUI & DocumentGroup

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller, documentgroup

My document-based app supports several different file types. It is currently written in SwiftUI using a `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`. I'm trying to convert to the new SwiftUI (v2) `DocumentGroup` paradigm in which you don't directly use a UIDocumentBrowserViewController. I need to let the user pick which kind of document to create when they tap the Create button in the browser. Using DocumentGroup, I don't see how this is possible. When you create a DocumentGroup, you have to specify the document right there:

```
var body: some Scene {
    DocumentGroup(newDocument: TextDocument()) { file in
        TextDocumentEditor(document: file.$document)
    }
}
```

When using UIKit, the browser calls a delegate function `didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler` that lets the app inject some UI for picking a document type, before proceeding on. In fact, what you can do is provide the document browser with a template file to be used for creating the new doc. Is that possible in SwiftUI 2?

Comment: I have some similar problems.. I don't see anything in the documentation related to this.l I don't see any delegate methods for showing documents or making some changes before a new document will be created.

Comment: Nope, stick with `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`. You can also present using the dedicated transition controller instead of pushing. DocumentGroup is a joke.

Comment: I am sticking with UIDocumentBrowserViewController for now. The other reason to do so is to handle conflict resolution. DocumentGroup and FileDocument don’t provide any support for this, that I see.

Comment: I feel too at least beta 6 its a toy.

Comment: Still a toy. Funny, macOS SwiftUI for once works better...